# Is a homeomorphism between complete DLOs necessarily an order isomorphism or order-reversing?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, order-theory

Let $(X,<)$ be a complete DLO without endpoints, whereby completeness, I mean Dedekind completeness. Let the topology on $X$ be the standard one induced by the open intervals. Then, I believe that $(X,<)\simeq (\mathbb{R},<)$ in the sense of homeomorphisms. If $f$ is the homeomorphism between them, is $f$ necessarily an order isomorphism or completely order-reversing?

The motivation for this question comes from trying to view Souslin's Problem as a topological problem. It asks whether or not such $(X,<)$ is order isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},<)$. I know that the resolution of this problem is independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but I fail to grasp why this problem is topological in nature unless there is some kind of correspondence between order isomorphicity and homeomorphicity in this situation. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The [long line](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)) is a Dedekind-complete DLO without endpoints which is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Indeed, since any linear order has a Dedekind completion and it's easy to build large DLOs without endpoints, there are Dedekind-complete DLOs without endpoints of arbitrary cardinality (this goes beyond the long line, whose cardinality is just that of $\mathbb{R}$ itself). The additional hypothesis in the Suslin problem, namely the *countable chain condition*, is quite important! @AlexKruckman